# Top column value?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using Laravel and want to get (in order) the countrys my users are from. At the moment each user has a column called `country`, I need to make some sort of collection of all the countrys, in order to how many users come from that country.

I've tried a join but it doesn't seem like that's what I'm looking for, can anyone help here?

Answer (score 0):

If I get you correctly, you might be looking out for this query, which will fetch you similar to below set of results.

```
$resSet = DB::table('users')
    ->select(country , DB::raw('COUNT(*) as userCount'))
            ->groupBy('country')
            ->orderBy('country')
            ->get();
```

[image]

Comment: How would I go about accessing the `country` and `userCount` on this, and how would I foreach it inside a view?

Comment: $resSet = json_decode($resSet, true);   foreach ($resSet as $row){  $country = $row['country']; $userCount = $row['useCount']; }